# CSS hover doesn't work

Tags: css

I am making a tabbed navigation menu via jQuery in my website.  All the individual tabs have the class `navBarLink` and here's the CSS pertaining to it:

```
.navBarLink:link,.navBarLink:visited
{
display:block;
height:27px;
width:120px;
color:#FFF;
background-color:#06C;
text-align:center;
padding:4px;
text-decoration:none;
border:0;
margin:2px 2px 0 2px;
}
.navBarLink:hover,.navBarLink:active
{
background-color:#FFF;
color:#06C;
border-bottom-style:solid;
border-bottom-color:#FFFFFF;
border-bottom-width:1px;
}
```

The problem is that the background color changes when I click on a tab but doesn't change when I hover on a tab.  Basically my hover and my click don't work simultaneously.  Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Open up your favorite page debugger (chrome dev/firebug/ie dev tools), select the element, and see how the CSS is being rendered.

Comment: It seems to work. http://jsfiddle.net/st46b/

Comment: Is `.navBarLink` an `a` element? If not, that could be the problem. I know at least some versions of IE won't use `:hover` rules unless they are applied to an `a` element.

Comment: maybe you have a typo in your html/css/js please provide more info

Comment: Could you provide the generated HTML?

Comment: Also, jQuery UI has tab functionality, maybe you should look into it: http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

Comment: @mikevoermans : but in ur case the click is not working!thats the problem both dont work simultaneously

Comment: @higfox They do work, when you have them in the same declaration they do the same thing. Tell the click to do something different and it will. http://jsfiddle.net/st46b/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/UnFhQ/

This works. (I removed the :link from the first css code, just so I could see the div's background color...) But click this and let us know what about the code doesn't work.
Thanks

Comment: haha, ya man it works wonders alongside Stackoverflow...I've been seeing it more and more on this site, it makes the "why doesn't this code work" question much much easier to debug and verify.